# wordpress comment form basic modifications

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP for the first time and in my child theme the comment.php file is quite poor compared to the WP default file.
I need to do simple modifications and I have found tutorials to follow (for instance [this](http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-easily-customize-wordpress-comment-form/)) but the problem is that the child theme shows me a different comment.php file.
I understand it's better not to modify WP default files so I'm happy with modifying what the child theme offers me.

What I need to know is how to concatenate 2 or more php functions.

I need to transform this: `<?php comment_form(); ?>`

into these: `<?php comment_form(array('comment_notes_after' => '')); ?>`

plus `<?php comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:')); ?>`

In other words, is there a way to append more PHP functions in one line? I mean, can I just add arrays separated by a comma, like `<?php comment_form(array('comment_notes_after' => '')),(array('title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:')); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add more then one key and values in the comment_form() function,

```
<?php 
  comment_form( array( 
    'comment_notes_after' => '', 
    'title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:'
  )); 
?>
```

Comment: @Criss You might want to accept and upvote answers that helped you.Click under the arrows

Comment: @Criss Editing title with SOLVED is not the way to closing this thread, You have to accept the answer to close this thread.